# Placement of `\vdots` looks strange with kpfonts-otf

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, kpfonts

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \mu_1\\
        \vdots\\
        \mu_n
    \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\vdots` does not seem very balanced:

[image]

With the normal version of `kpfonts` the result looks fine:

[image]

Is there something that can be done within LaTeX to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy\originalvdots\vdots
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \mu_1\\
        \vdots\\
        \mu_n
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \mu_1\\
        \originalvdots\\
        \mu_n
    \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\originalvdots` command uses the period from Computer Modern, but it's a detail not so important.

With some measuring…

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy\originalvdots\vdots
% \usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy\unicodevdots\vdots
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\vdots}{}{\mathrel{\loweredvdots}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\loweredvdots}{\mathpalette\loweredvdots@\relax}
\newcommand{\loweredvdots@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\unicodevdots$}%
  \vrule width \z@ height 2.25\ht\z@ depth 0.012\ht\z@
  \raisebox{0.25\height}{\usebox\z@}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \mu_1\\
        \vdots\\
        \mu_n
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \mu_1\\
        \originalvdots\\
        \mu_n
    \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Two quick questions: 1) I thought that adding `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[range={\vdots}]` would be the same as your first approach, but in fact it does not work. Why?  2) Is it safe to use your second approach (the `\loweredvdots` one) in a package?  I mean if the `kpfonts-otf` get fixed some day, would those extra code cause trouble?

Comment: @Jinwen In legacy TeX, `\vdots` is built by stacking periods; in `unicode-math` it’s a single glyph. I’m afraid that the here proposed hack only works for the specific font.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Actually, in my document class, the font configuration is fixed and uses the `KpMath-Regular.otf` from [this line](https://github.com/Jinwen-XU/minimalist/blob/b00c2525733f52504304a93188074b619660fe5f/minimalist.dtx#L655) on, thus I'm willing to know if your proposed hack can serve as a temporary fix to this problem in this particular document class (the thing I'm afraid is that when the OTF file get updated, this hack might cause extra trouble).

Comment: @Jinwen I can't know the plans of KpMath developers… On the other hand, it's not that I like so much the standard output of `\vdots`…

Comment: @Jinwen Btw your issue is not specific to `kpfonts-otf` (try `Libertinus-Math`, `Latin-Modern-Math`, Erewhon-Math, ...) the `unicode-math` glyph `\vdots` (U+22EE) is always vertically centred on the math axis, this causes your issue.  As `kpfonts-otf` developer I do not intend to change this, so you can  reliably apply @egreg' patch.

Comment: @DanielFlipo Thank you for this info, and for you great work on this font!

Answer (score 1):

In OpTeX, this problem doesn't exists. The original `\vdots` keeps unchanged even though the Unicode math with KP fonts and otf-math is initialized. The control sequence `\unicodevdots` is ready to access the Unicode vdots character. Compare:

```
\fontfam[kp]
$$
  \pmatrix{\mu_1\cr \vdots\cr \mu_n}, \quad \pmatrix{\mu_1\cr \unicodevdots\cr \mu_n}
$$
\bye
```

Of course, you can say `\let\vdots=\unicodevdots` if you like the Unicode character. See section 2.6 of the document optex-math for more information.